# Literature on the polynomials and equations, in structures with zero-divisors

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, associative-algebras, zeroes

I need literature about zeroes of polynomials and equation resolution in associative algebraic structures with zero-divisors, but I am having difficulties to find it.

For example, there is literature in the resolution of quadratic(and remarks on other degrees) in quaternions and split-quaternions.

It seems that search engines do something with the keyword zero, that has two meanings in this context, this is, zero-divisor and zeroes of the polynomials.

So far I do not find ways to more concrete examples.
It would be fine also, algebraic literature ( as opposed to specific examples )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **associative algebras**, as your required, see Plotkin, *Algebras with the same (algebraic) geometry*, Israel J. Math., 96 (2) (1996), 511–522.

This is, being more precise, part of this nice relatively new field of Universal Algebraic Geometry which discuss such things.

For a survey I recommend A. Shevlyakov, *Lectures notes in universal algebraic geometry*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02743.

---

**EDIT** depending on the kind of question you are interested in, pherhaps the theory of (associative) PI-algebras might be also interesting. For this I recommend V. Drensky's *Free Algebras and PI-algebras*.

Comment: I forget to add other details, specifically, the property of multiplicative inverse for nonzero elements. In anycase, I will examine the literature that you had provided ;)